# i want to Add an onBlur and on focus to form elements

Tags: javascript

So on a specific page I have some number of form elements for example, user name and user email.

How can I add a specific onblur event and onfocus to all of the form elements dynamically on the page by using Java script?
`

```
<label for="name">Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" tabindex="10" />
<p>
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="text" value="your email" name="email" id="email" tabindex="20" />
</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jquery to get particular DOM element by name or Id and apply `.blur(...)`:

```
$('#name').blur(function() {
   ...
});
```

If you want to use "pure" javascript:

```
document.getElementById('name').onBlur = function () {
   ...
};
```

Comment: `.blur()` is sufficient ;)

Comment: No i don't want to do it with jQuery,is there any way to do it with javascript?

Comment: @RajabSaleem You clearly marked your question with the jQuery tag. Please be more precise/selective in the future.

Comment: It's important to remember that jQuery *is* JavaScript. If it can be done in jQuery, it can be done (albeit with potentially more blood, sweat and tears) in plain JavaScript. But if you don't want to use jQuery don't tag your question with jQuery.

Comment: i know this but i had to done it in javascript man i have my reasons!

Comment: @RajabSaleem Don't know why you'd get so worked up about it. The point of tagging is to ensure that it is discoverable by tags and searches, and tags are also an indicator of the relevant topics/skills. If jQuery is listed, of course members will have the impression that you will accept jQ-based solution. As simple as that. Take a chill pill.